# Why my Wordpress website is showing nothing?

Tags: wordpress, web, plugins, wordpress-theming

My Wordpress is only showing me the following in the picture "My First Heading" and "My First paragraph". I tried to add themes and customise it but it is not changing. Also, I have added another page and I made it as homepage of the website, but still it does not work. Besides I reset my whole website and nothing happened.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough points to put a comment, so I will post here. It is not possible to give a straight-forward answer to this, since there may be many reasons why this is showing. Here are some general tips that may help:

1. Check via ftp if your root directory contains any index.html files. If yes, remove them. WordPress uses index.php to load.
2. Go to WP Admin and switch off all plugins.
3. Turn on the default WordPress theme (Twenty Twenty or Twenty One, depending on your WordPress version)
4. Contact your host (send a ticket)
5. If none of this work, create a full site backup, then reinstall WordPress (make sure there are no other files on your server that can mess with the installation)